# Unity 3D gameobjects not moving

Tags: unity-game-engine

In unity the game object(player) doesn't move even tho I have got the same scripts and game objects (with the same components and values) from the other game and the movement works in the other game. I have tried restarting my computer and making a new project. The movespeed values and drag values are the same as the other game where the movement works too.

Comment: You forgot something, go through everything again. There is no magic involved.

Comment: You should at least post the part of the codes that is not working and give us the expected outcomes.

Comment: There are only 2 scripts 1 controls the camera and the other moves the player the one that moves the player doesn't work there are no errors in the conole either

Answer (score 0):

> The movespeed values and **drag** values are the same as the other game where the movement works too.

If you're using touch controls, have you added `EventSystem` and `StandaloneInputModule` to your scene ( older versions of Unity might also need `TouchInputModule`)